# Doorkeeper authorize also redirect_uri subpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I am developing an `oauth 2.0` server using `Doorkeeper`.

What I need is to 'customize' implicit flow authorization in order to let sub-path of the client `redirect_uri` to be authorized as well.

**Example**

```
Client ( id: "123", name: "example", redirect_uri: "http://www.foo.com")

request : client_id : "123", scope:"-" redirect_uri:"http://www.foo.com" 

=> token

request : client_id : "123", scope:"-" redirect_uri:"http://www.foo.com/bar/whatever" 

=> invalid redirect_uri (i want token)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Here are a few posts regarding issues you might stumble upon.. see https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/?s=doorkeeper